# Drawing cube map and texture array on NVidia cards doesn't work

Tags: textures, rendering, cubemap, nvidia

I have small problem with shadow maps preview. After binding shadow framebuffer I bind proper texture to store depth in it and then render the whole scene. When I read that values in shader to calculate shadows everything works as I expect on every tested computers. But when I want draw this textures on 2D quads I have it working only on AMD cards. On NVidia all I have is white empty fields. This happens only with cube maps and array texture.

Here is screen:
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Creating framebuffer:

```
if(!_s_buffer)glGenFramebuffers(1, &_s_buffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, _s_buffer);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, _depth.get(), 0); // set anything to framebuffer to avoid "framebuffer incomplete" error

glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Could the problem be caused by using one framebuffer for cube map and array texture and switch between them in code (one time depth attachment is cube map - `glFramebufferTexture2D` with `textarget` set to proper cube map face - and another time it is array texture - `glFramebufferTextureLayer`).

Could you help me with this? I'm looking for a solution but without results. Maybe you met with this kind of problem. If more code is need I can post it.

Comment: Do you check for OpenGL errors/warnings using [KHR_debug](http://renderingpipeline.com/2013/09/opengl-debugging-with-khr_debug/)?  If not, that would be the first step.  It's possible you are doing something "wrong" according to GL, and AMD's drivers are okay with it but NV's aren't.

Comment: I didn't know about such extension, thanks for it. I checked it and I have a lot of glUniform errors on both AMD and NVidia cards (errors are the same, only description is more precise on AMD). Here is one of them:
glUniformMatrix3fv* parameter <location> has specified an invalid value '5': not the location of an active uniform in the default uniform block.
I read info about this uniform using glGetActiveUniform and it shows:
mat3 NormalMatrix 5, where the last number is location.
For me, it looks ok, I have no idea what can I do with this errors.